# What is the difference between declaring and defining a pointer in C/C++?

Tags: pointers, memory, dynamic, declaration, allocation

What is the exact difference between *dummy* and *node* pointers in the following line?

ListNode *dummy = new ListNode(0), *node;

ListNode is a structure.

Answer (score 0):

THis line

```
 ListNode *dummy = new ListNode(0), *node;
```

is really

```
 ListNode *dummy = new ListNode(0);
 ListNode *node;
```

both lines create a pointer to a ListNode

The first one also creates a ListNode instance on the heap and sets dummy to point at it

THe second line creates a pointer that is unitiialized, it points nowhere valid.

These are both declaration and definition.

- Its the first time that the names have been seen = declaration
- they are actually instantiated and complete = definition

the fact that one points somewhere and the other does not is not relevant, the pointers themselves have been declared and defined